# I'd like to know the spelling of a word, a synonym of unknown

Tags: synonyms, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling

I'm used to watching American TV Series all the time. I watch them with Italian subtitles, so I misspell many words. Many of them are not so difficult to figure out, but there's one that I just cannot figure out what is. I have tried to find it in many ways (Google Translate and many other sites) with no results.

The word sounds like ***jen though*** (in Italian I would write it *gen do*). It seems to mean "unknown" in police jargon: when the police find a corpse with no identity, they call it a ‘jen though’.

What can this word be?

Comment: John Doe? As in an unknown person?

Comment: Oh,  I think you mean "Jane Doe" the name used by Police for unidentified females.

Comment: The corollary question is "What is the etymology of jane/john doe?"

Comment: @Blessed Geek - ask and you shall receive. :-)

Comment: The next corollary is "How popular is American TV and movies across the world?"

Comment: Language barriers. That's funny.

Answer (score 47):

When a person’s identity is unknown (which is often the case when a dead body is found, before the body is identified) or must be anonymised, but the person still needs to be entered into some kind of system that requires a name, *placeholder names* are often used.

The most common placeholder names are **John Doe** for males and **Jane Doe** for females (as mentioned in Håkan and Jim’s comments to the question itself); sometimes just **Doe** is used on its own for persons of unknown sex. What you’re describing sounds like *Jane Doe*. Another common version has *Richard Roe* and *Jane Roe*, which is most famously found in the common name of a US Supreme Court decision regarding abortion, known as [*Roe v. Wade*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roe_v._Wade) (*Jane Roe* being here the plaintiff’s anonymised name).

There is a lengthy [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Doe) about these placeholder names, with lots of additional information.